# C++20: Unable to properly use concepts to enforce that a constructor template parameter is a base of one of two types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am a bit of a noob to C++20, and I only recently have been able to use C++11/14 so I am trying to update my knowledge and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to use concept requirements. My goal is to ensure that a class of type SocketAddress only takes a type of IpV4Address or IpV6Address in its constructor, while using a template constructor so that I don't have to have 6 different constructor definitions for passing by value, ref, or r-value.

I am able to compile the class of SocketAddress when it is defined as:

```
template <typename T>
concept IpAddress = std::is_base_of<IpV4Address, T>::value || std::is_base_of<IpV6Address, T>::value;

class SocketAddress
{
public:

   SocketAddress() = delete;

   template <typename T> requires IpAddress<T>
   SocketAddress(T&& ip_address, const uint16_t port) noexcept;

};

template <typename T> requires IpAddress<T>
SocketAddress::SocketAddress(T&& ip_address, const uint16_t port) noexcept :
   m_ip_address(std::forward<T>(ip_address))   
{

}
```

However, when I actually attempt to construct a SocketAddress in my tests I get the compiler error:

```
error C2661: 'CrossPlatformSockets::SocketAddress::SocketAddress': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

Where my test code is:

```
SocketAddress socket_address(IpV4Address("127.0.0.1"), 8000);
```

I'm not really sure what I am missing here such that the compiler is unable to detect the constructor I have defined that takes two inputs. If anyone can help me learn how to use these concepts or point out what is wrong I would greatly appreciate it! I know I could not use concepts, and use some form of static assert/ugly SNFINAE-type solution, however I want to learn the new stuff!

Comment: Since you used `T &&`, try doing `requires IpAddress<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>`

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/9W6YzvTx9).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Great suggestion, should've added that before. This doesn't fix my issue, but it certainly was going to be required.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Good point... I ommitted some detail from my example on how the IpV4Address is constructed, but when I did what you did and made a simplified implementation it seems to work, so it seems the issue is actually just with the argument itself. That compiler argument is very misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dumb but a clean and rebuild literally fixed my problem.

Additionally given @PatrickRoberts suggestion, my concept is now defined as:

```
template <typename T>
concept IpAddress = std::is_base_of<IpV4Address, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value || 
                    std::is_base_of<IpV6Address, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value;
```